# Way to get Titanfall 2 on Steam if you already own it on Origin?

Tags: steam, origin, titanfall-2

Recently Titanfall 2 became available on the Steam store. I already own the game on Origin but would like to get it on Steam so I don't have to deal with Origin as much. Is there any way to do this, such as entering a code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, there is no way to transfer an Origin copy of any game to Steam. This was confirmed by an EA Community Manager on an [Answer HQ](https://answers.ea.com/t5/Origin-Client-Web-Technical/transfer-origin-games-to-steam/m-p/9208921/highlight/true#M85117) thread:

> Hey all, it is not currently possible to move games from Origin to any other platform.
>
> I will pass your feedback on.
>
> Darko

Comment: This is just bad because items price like prime titans skins or everything else are cheaper on Steam which is just unfair.